# Why are my events getting called so many times? [React + Electron]

Tags: reactjs, electron

**Summary**

I'm building a desktop app using React and Electron. It's purpose is to install files to coder defined directory. Files come from amazon S3. I'm using a Material UI Framework for a loading bar, and SnackBar popup to show user success. To download, I am using this library: https://github.com/tytech3/node-s3-client

Using this library exposes the byte values coming in and total byte values we need, therefore giving me a percentage to my progress bar.

**The problem**

I am using events, namely ipcMain and ipcRenderer, to pass this information. 
Main.js (the file that plays with the OS):

```
 ipcMain.once('downloadDir', (event, arg) => {

  var percentage = 10;

  ipcMain.on('downloaderPercentage', (event, arg) => {
    event.reply('downloadPercentage', percentage);
    percentage += 10;
    console.log("Main % val: " + percentage);
  })

  ipcMain.on('clear', (event, arg) => {
    percentage = 0;
  })

})
```

and Test.js (my react component):

```
  installFiles = (version)  => {
    this.openSnack = false;
    console.log(version);

    this.setState({currentDownload: "Downloading File: " + version, downloading: true})
    ipcRenderer.send('downloadDir', version);
    ipcRenderer.send("downloaderPercentage")

    var that = this;

    ipcRenderer.on('downloadPercentage', (event, arg) => {
          console.log("Testpage %: " + arg);
          that.percentage = arg
          setTimeout(function(){
            if(isMounted && (arg < 100)) {
              ipcRenderer.send("downloaderPercentage")
              that.setState({percentage: arg});
          }
           else{
            console.log("else statement")
            that.resultMessage = 'Installation Successful'
            that.openSnack = true;
            that.setState({currentDownload: '', percentage: 100})
            ipcRenderer.send('clear');
      }}, 500)
      })
    }
```

I render multiple cards that have an install button that all use this function `'installFiles'` above. 
The first button works beautifully, just as I designed. But if you add another card with another button, it will run ipcRenderer event multiple times, and it will hit the ending else statement 12 times. If you add another, the numbers increases. I have tried messing with removing event listeners but that doesn't work.

**TLDR**
Does anyone know why my event listeners are being hit so many times once they are called again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. The event listeners were never removed. Added 2 lines (see lines starting with +) to remove listeners. I believe ipcRenderer.on actually creates a new listener, which is why i was getting more and more.

```
    ipcRenderer.on('downloadPercentage', (event, arg) => {
      console.log("Testpage %: " + arg);
      that.percentage = arg
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(isMounted && (arg < 100)) {
          ipcRenderer.send("downloaderPercentage")
          that.setState({percentage: arg});
      }
       else{
        console.log("else statement")
        that.resultMessage = 'Installation Successful'
        that.openSnack = true;
        that.setState({currentDownload: '', percentage: 100})
        ipcRenderer.send('clear');
       + ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('downloadPercentage');
       + ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('downloaderPercentage');

  }}, 500)
  })
  this.setState({currentDownload: "Installing File: " + version})
}
```